# MailChimp Account Issue

Tags: mailchimp

I have just created a MailChimp Account, then I created a list and added a user, I created a campaign and then selected a template; I edited the template and sent it to the List. But after that I got the following error. Please tell me how to fix this issue as we are on deadline and have to deliver thing in a month.

[image: this is the error message I am being shown]

Comment: This isn't anything we can fix here - this is a problem between you and MailChimp's support. Are you sure you weren't violating their [Acceptable Use Policy](http://mailchimp.com/legal/acceptable_use/)?

Comment: Well I am not quite sure,, but I just selected a template and added a few lines with headers and footers , i was just testing how it works. I have been trying to resolve this , and created 3 accounts subsequently but everytime my account got disabled. I have contacted the mailchimp regarding the issue but their response is very unsatisfactory, not clear what to do.

Answer (score 0):

While exploring the MailChimp API, We came to know that the current connection limit is 10 simultaneous connections per user account. If Limit crosses then error message will be returned.

Is this limit same for free forever plan account and other price plans account?

Kindly let me know the answer.

Thanks
Sonia

Comment: I have moved to Mandrill (an Addon for Mailchimp) which serves the same purpose but with little effort and restrictions compared to MailChimp, so I have no idea whether the above is true or not.